# make Installer metapackage to require SIMBL?

Tags: installation, packagemaker, simbl

Using PackageMaker, how do I make a .(m)pkg that will require that SIMBL is installed - if it's installed, the installation should simply proceed, otherwise, SIMBL should be installed before installing my SIMBL plugin?

I tried simply dragging in SIMBL.pkg to the left-hand pane, but somehow all the resources and `InstallationCheck` script got lost, so that's probably not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend just installing SIMBL without checking. These days, because InputManagers can only go in /Library (and not ~/Library), SIMBL is always in the same place. In this case, installing SIMBL can't really hurt -- the author doesn't update SIMBL often at all these days, so it's very unlikely that you'll accidentally "downgrade" a user's SIMBL installation. (The [last release of SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) was in 2006.)

To add SIMBL to your project, you can choose "Add Package Reference" from the "gear" button in the lower-left. You can also just drag the SIMBL folder (from InputManagers) into a new choice (see "New Choice" under the same gear button) and set its install location manually.

As an example, [here is a .pmdoc file](http://files.radbox.org/scalp-install.pmdoc.zip) for a SIMBL plugin I wrote called [Scalp](http://pygmysoftware.com/software/scalp/).